# restore .bak error cyclic redundancy check in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, runtime-error, backup, restore, crc

when I want to restoring my last month backup file for SQL Server, after 95% I faced with this error:
cyclic redundancy check

I have no other backup more, what I can to do!

Comment: You can do: Read "How to ask" and use correct case shift.

Comment: Try executing the restore with the [`CONTINUE_AFTER_ERROR` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql).